# Windows settings restrictions "Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization"

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm currently trying to install Windows sub-system for Linux, but I need to enable Developer mode on my computer settings.

However, I couldn't enable those settings because of this message *"Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization"*. This is my personal system.

I'm running on Windows 10 Pro

I've tried all the methods listed on [this website](https://lecrabeinfo.net/windows-10-solution-probleme-message-erreur-des-parametres-sont-masques-ou-geres-par-votre-organisation.html#methode-n2-en-restaurant-les-parametres-de-telemetrie-et-de-confidentialite)

- by reconfiguring the working group
- by restoring telemetry and privacy settings
- via the local group policy editor

None of them worked

I've been scratched my head on this for several hours, please need some help !

Comment: Welcome to SU. Is this provided by your employer or scool, or is it your own system? If the first, you should discuss with the IT department. If it's yours, have a peek [here](https://windowsreport.com/some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization/) - sorry but I don't speak French so can't say if these are the same instructions.

Comment: No problem, I'm fluent in English, thanks for your greetings. I get it on second hand from a guy that has the hobby of repairing and "custom" old PC it's possible that he get it from his job, but I can't say more. From my personal perspective, I use it for personal use, and I'm connected on a public Ethernet connection from my university residency. @Peregrino69

Comment: @JawadBounaâs Is your computer/account part of the university's domain?

Comment: Oh yes, it belongs to you, not to school or something :-) Sorry, I forgot to say - it's better to edit your question to add new info to the question than answering in comments, so relevant details are immediately seen without digging it up from commentaries. I added the "personal system" info now for you. Do add answer to @NotTheDr01ds's question

Comment: Thanks Peregrino69 glad you make the edit, and no it's not a part of the uni domain @NotTheDr01ds.

Comment: Also, it may be relevant to say that since I get this PC I've never created any "personal" user profile, it's running on a user profile like "HP600" with no passwords attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment on my previous (now deleted, since it not relevant) answer, you mentioned:

> I go to the accounts setting, and I've noticed that the Microsoft email address linked to my current user account is related to my uni email address

> do you think this might be where the problem came from?

Yes, that's most likely the problem.  Perhaps you installed Microsoft Office from your university's subscription, which required you to login with that address.  There's a checkbox when you do so that says something like, "Allow this organization to manage my device."  It's selected by default, so unless you intentionally deselected it, some University settings took effect.

I haven't had this situation myself, but from [this Reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/fzqj03/comment/fn5ntxp/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) the solution should be to:

- Remove the school account from the Windows "Account" settings
- Log out of your school account in Microsoft Office (if applicable) under "Account" in one of the apps.
- I would reboot and try to install WSL.  You actually should *not* need to enable Developer Mode.  WSL required Developer Mode at one point, but that was about 4 years ago.  It should work without Developer Mode.  You may have thought that you needed Developer Mode due to problems with the system being managed by your school.
- If all is working fine, then leave the Uni account off of it.  If you do need to add it back, look for the "Allow this organization to manage ..." setting and make sure it is deselected.